# Mostrar modal, ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hola a todos estoy tratanto de mandar datos a un modal pero no cargan los datos que me interesan, si habilito el dataType json el modal no abre y va directamente al error, por ahora hice pruebas con cargar todo el json y si lo hace, el problema es cuando quiero elementos en especìfico

```
   $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/plan/modal_view/',
  data: {id_selected: id},
  //dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
     //info = JSON.parse(data);
     for (var i in info) {
        //$("#tel").html(data[i].tel_professionnel)
     }
     $("#title-modal").html(id);
     $(".modal-body").html(data);
     $("#modal").modal('show');
  }, error: function () {
     alert('Information non disponible');
  }
```

})

Esta es la funciòn de en mi controlador,‘listPerso’ almacena los objetos json  y lo demàs son los datos que quiero mostrar en el modal, pero aparece somo indice indefinido

```
    public function modal_view()
{
    $id_selected = $this->input->post("id_selected");


    $data ['listPerso'] = $this->plan_model->get_infoBureau($id_selected);


    foreach($data as $value){
    $data2 = [
        'tel_professionnel'=> $value['tel_professionnel'],
        'nom_usage' => $value['nom_usage'],
        'prenom'=> $value['prenom']
        ];

    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    $this->load->view('bureau_info', $data, $data2);

}
```

Vista

```
    <?php if (is_array($listPerso)): ?>
                <?php foreach ($listPerso as $data) { ?>
                    <card class="card">
                    <p id="nom"> <?php echo $data->personne->nom_usage ?>
                        <?php echo $data->personne->prenom ?></p>
                    <p id="tel"> <?php echo $data->tel_professionnel ?></p>
                    </card>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

en la vista esos son los datos que requiero, en consola si cargan correctamente pero no logro pasarlos al modal

Al habilitar  el dataType directamente lanza el error y no abre el modal ni aparece el console.log, si solo pongo el console carga esto:

```
{"listPerso":[{"id_localisation":28,"tel_professionnel":"0476857874","id_badge":null,"commentaire":null,"created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"25\/02\/2020","updated_at":"25\/02\/2020","personne":{"id_personne":24,"mail_usage":"dugarda@gmail.com","genre":"M.","nom_patronyme":"Dugard","nom_usage":"Dugard","prenom":"Alexandre","prenom2":null,"prenom3":null,"date_de_naissance":"25\/08\/1982","tel_personnel":"0325859674","ville_naissance":"Grenoble","num_dep_naissance":"38","code_pays_naissance":"FR","code_nationalite":"FR","code_nationalite2":null,"nom_contact_urgence":"Martins","prenom_contact_urgence":"marissa","tel_contact_urgence":"0476969865","photo":"","autorisation_diff_ext":false,"autorisation_diff_int":false,"etat":null,"fin_titre_sejour":"","observation":null,"created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"25\/02\/2020","updated_at":"25\/02\/2020","info_prof":{"id_info_pro":23,"id_personne":24,"tel_pro_portable":"06 63 52 41 52","tel_pro":"04 76 25 36 15","date_visite_medicale":"19\/08\/2018","date_entretien_annuel":"","date_soutenance_hdr":"05\/06\/2019","date_pedr":"","medecin":false,"login_labo":"dugarda","date_entree_labo":"","date_depart_labo":"","created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"25\/02\/2020","updated_at":"25\/02\/2020","formation_hs":true},"adresse_permanente":{"id_adresse":19,"adresse":"158 Rue Martine","ville":"Grenoble","code_postal":"38100","code_pays":"FR","created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"25\/02\/2020","updated_at":"25\/02\/2020","pays":"FRANCE"},"adresse_temp":null,"pays_naissance":"FRANCE","nationalite":"Fran\u00e7aise ","nationalite2":null,"mail_perso":"dugarda@perso.com"},"bureau":{"id_bureau":103,"numero_bureau":"B223","capacite_nb_places_max":6,"num_bureau_archi":null,"site":{"id_site":3,"nom_site":"Gipsa-lab","adresse_geographique":"11 rue des Math\u00e9matiques, Grenoble Campus, BP46, F - 38402 SAINT MARTIN D'HERES Cedex","adresse_postale":null,"tel_site":null,"fax_site":null,"ville":"ST MARTIN D HERES","latitude":null,"longitude":null},"type_bureau":{"id_type_bureau":2,"type_bureau":"Doctorants\/Stagiaires"}}},{"id_localisation":29,"tel_professionnel":"0476857998","id_badge":null,"commentaire":null,"created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"25\/02\/2020","updated_at":"25\/02\/2020","personne":{"id_personne":25,"mail_usage":"mahop@gmail.com","genre":"M.","nom_patronyme":"Maho","nom_usage":"Maho","prenom":"Pierre","prenom2":null,"prenom3":null,"date_de_naissance":"30\/09\/1976","tel_personnel":"0952416374","ville_naissance":"Nice","num_dep_naissance":"06","code_pays_naissance":"FR","code_nationalite":"FR","code_nationalite2":null,"nom_contact_urgence":"Smith","prenom_contact_urgence":"alain","tel_contact_urgence":"0476969856","photo":"","autorisation_diff_ext":true,"autorisation_diff_int":false,"etat":null,"fin_titre_sejour":"","observation":null,"created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"25\/02\/2020","updated_at":"25\/02\/2020","info_prof":{"id_info_pro":24,"id_personne":25,"tel_pro_portable":"06 63 52 45 21","tel_pro":"04 76 25 36 87","date_visite_medicale":"19\/01\/2018","date_entretien_annuel":"","date_soutenance_hdr":"","date_pedr":"","medecin":false,"login_labo":"mahop","date_entree_labo":"","date_depart_labo":"","created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"25\/02\/2020","updated_at":"25\/02\/2020","formation_hs":true},"adresse_permanente":{"id_adresse":13,"adresse":"10 Rue Platon","ville":"Lyon","code_postal":"69000","code_pays":"FR","created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"25\/02\/2020","updated_at":"25\/02\/2020","pays":"FRANCE"},"adresse_temp":null,"pays_naissance":"FRANCE","nationalite":"Fran\u00e7aise ","nationalite2":null,"mail_perso":"mahop@perso.com"},"bureau":{"id_bureau":103,"numero_bureau":"B223","capacite_nb_places_max":6,"num_bureau_archi":null,"site":{"id_site":3,"nom_site":"Gipsa-lab","adresse_geographique":"11 rue des Math\u00e9matiques, Grenoble Campus, BP46, F - 38402 SAINT MARTIN D'HERES Cedex","adresse_postale":null,"tel_site":null,"fax_site":null,"ville":"ST MARTIN D HERES","latitude":null,"longitude":null},"type_bureau":{"id_type_bureau":2,"type_bureau":"Doctorants\/Stagiaires"}}}]}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Ok, si dejas el `dataType: 'json'` no tienes que usar `JSON.parse`, y para recorrer los datos con el `for` tienes que abrir el array en su clave `listPerso`, pues según lo que muestra es ahí donde está el array de datos, algo así: `$.each(data.listPerso, function (index,item) {
    console.log(item.id_localisation); //etc
});`  es decir, usarías `item.clave` para leer cada valor, donde `clave` es el nombre de cada clave como `tel_professionnel, id_badge` etc.

Comment: He tratado de hacerlo , pero me aparece que listPerso no està definida y no entiendo porque no me carga el modal cuando habilito el dataType (no uso el parse)

Comment: El JSON que pusiste ahí está incompleto, quizás sea por eso que Javascript no puede usar parse correctamente. Si cargas la url `http://localhost/plan/modal_view/`en un navegador o postman (fuera de tu ajax) te devuelve el JSON completo?

Comment: @Vlady tiene razón, para que funcione el JSON tiene que ser válido. He copiado/pegado tu JSON en un validador y no pasa la validación. Eso es esencial para que el código funcione.

Comment: si me devulve esto, no copie completo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás queriendo acceder directamente a las propiedades:

```
   $("#tel").html(data[i].tel_professionnel)
```

Pero hay un objeto previo (listPerso):

```
   `{"listPerso": [{"elemento 1"}, {"elemento 2 ..."}, {"... elemento x"}]}`
```

Entonces, debes acceder a `data.listPerso[elemento].propiedad`

Prueba con esto:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/plan/modal_view/',
      data: {id_selected: id},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
         for (var i in data.listPerso) {
            console.log(data.listPerso[i].tel_professionnel);
            //$("#tel").html(data.listPerso[i].tel_professionnel)
         }
         $("#title-modal").html(id);
         $(".modal-body").html(data);
         $("#modal").modal('show');
      }, error: function () {
         alert('Information non disponible');
      }
 });
```

Luego, tienes otro problema y es que en cada iteración asignas el nuevo valor al mismo elemento, porque la id siempre es la misma `"#tel"`, pero eso ya es aparte de esta pregunta.

Comment: Gracias , ya lo intentè de esa forma pero sigue sin reconocer listPerso

Comment: Copié el JSON de tu pregunta para probar y funcionó correctamente, no pude agregar un snippet a la respuesta, quizá por la longitud de la línea.